# Show an external internet calendar (ICS) in everybody's Outlook on 365

Tags: exchange, group-policy, microsoft-office-365

we're using M365 with more platforms - Outlook on Mac, iOS, Windows and web, as well as Calendar.app on iOS and macOS.

And we have an external HR web app which has an internet calendar such as `webcal://exampleHR.com/cal/feed/1234-5678-90` with holidays and sick days.

When I add this location via Outlook web app - **Add calendar > Subscribe from web > Add to: My calendars** - it works nicely - it even shows up as a second calendar on macOS and iOS.

But - is there a way, a **group policy**, perhaps, to add it to *every user* in the organisation, automatically? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to my search, I found a known issue which says[You can't add an Internet calendar in Outlook 2019, Outlook 2016, and Outlook for Microsoft 365](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/calendaring/cannot-add-an-internet-calendar) in Microsoft Document.
So, as the document mentioned, you may use Outlook Web App (OWA) to work around the issue.
Because OWA doesn't have this authentication header behavior, so you can open the Internet calendar successfully.

So, given this case, a proper workaround is to send this link to members of your organization and ask them to manually add it.